# React 'Cannot GET /' suddenly appeard without any changes to code

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am learning react and javascript by simply trying to make some website. Today when I was implementings routes to handle /login I ended up in a position where I can't even load my main page "/". When I run my "node server.js", every time I try load website I get this 'Cannot GET /' error.

I was playing with routes, retruning response from mysql to console etc. Everything was working fine and I had no trouble loading main page. So I fianlly need bodyParser to post a request, but I already had this in my server.js so I processed. Unfortunately, I came up at some errors while I was trying to send post request from my main page to /login. Website was still loading fine, I was just getting error about bodyparse in console where I run server.js. Just for learning purpose I deleted these two lines from my server.js

```html
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I wanted to see what error I would get now. I don't think that's reason I am gettig this error. Anyway, from now I couldn't load my main page anymore accessing http://localhost:3000/ . I am just not sure if this occured when I deleted these two lines or after I make them back. From now I am always getting this same error about "cannot get /". My code looks the same as it was when working fine.

I am not using index.html file only .js components. So I can't route "/" to index.html.

My server.js

```html
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host : '111.222.335.441',
 user : 'w6732ite',
 password : 'j52523545',
 database : 'w643636436346te'}
);

connection.connect();



app.listen(PORT, () =>{
 console.log('App running on port ${PORT}');
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./app/routes/approutes.js')(app);
```

I read about this error and it is some routing issue so I don't think that deleting these two lines was my problem, but after I make them back website just stopped loading. I was trying to reseting everything couple times, still no luck.

Edit:I refreshed the website once - it worked, first time after 30mins(still no changes to code). Then I refreshed again and I can't load it anymore.

Comment: You don’t have any code to handle the route, and that’s why you’re getting the error. You have to add a handler like described here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: I read about this and I will add this soon. I mean that it was working fine just for main page with login form without it. Until suddenly it stopped working and now I always get this error.

Comment: are you sure you added those lines back in the correct place @chrunchips123? I think they're supposed to be called before `app.listen`.

Comment: I forget to set server on port 3001 and react app on 3000. Instead both were listening 3000. I have no idea why it was working like that for some time. Now it is working.